# How to find the memory leak in virtual address in android?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, dalvik

There's a button which can play video in our app named `MediaCenter.apk`. Recently we found each time we play and exit the video. The virtual address of the mediacenter process increases about 5784KB (but the physical address remains the same), so the process crashes in video player stress test because at then the virtual address is not enough. I used command `pmap -x pid` to check the virtual memory usage of the mediacenter process and found the increased 5784KB was used by 
`/data/dalvik-cache/system@app@MediaCenter.apk@classes.dex`.

```
65b29000    5784       8       0       0  r--p  /data/dalvik-cache/system@app@MediaCenter.apk@classes.dex
```

I found the size of the file `/data/dalvik-cache/system@app@MediaCenter.apk@classes.dex` was nearly equal to 5784KB. It seemed that the whole file was memory-mapped to the mediacenter process. But how can I find out in which stage the file was memory-mapped in the process? And how to find why the virtual address is not released after the video player exits?

Answer (score 0):

Android hprof tool gives the memory usage of your app process.
Below is the link,
https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-hprof.html

To know the max heap allowed on your device is by adding below code in yout App.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
```

Comment: Thanks. But it seems hprof can be only used to analyze the physical memory usage of app process. In my case there's memory leak in virtual address rather than the physical address.

Comment: In my aunderstanding the virtual address is the heap space (RAM usage)  .The physical memory nothing but the apk size on the filesystem (Nand mem) . hprof does the heap analysis.

Comment: Sorry, here the virtual address I mean is the linux process virtual address, the physical address is the RAM.